# Calling a Server-Side @AuraEnabled

Tags: apex

So I have followed the developer guide but for some reason my code doesn't work. I have simplified the code.

Component:

```
<lightning:button label="Call server" onclick="{!c.test}"/>
```

Controller:

```
  test: function(component, event, helper)
  {     
    var action = component.get('c.testMethod');
     action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
           alert("INCOMPLETE");
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });        
 }
```

Server/apex code:

```
 @AuraEnabled
 public static String testMethod()
 { 
  return ('Hello from the server');               
 }
```

There is no alert when I press the button from the Component and I do not understand why.

Comment: can you provide full code of component ? What error do you have? in debug log or browser console?

Comment: You just missed with call action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You just missed with calling server-side action to the queue**

```
    test: function(component, event, helper)
      {     
        var action = component.get('c.testMethod');
         action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
               alert("INCOMPLETE");
            }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });  

   $A.enqueueAction(action);    

    // A client-side action could cause multiple events, 
    // which could trigger other events and 
    // other server-side action calls.
    // $A.enqueueAction adds the server-side action to the queue.
 }
```

Comment: @Mguy Welcome .........